# How to recognize / convert a tricky limit of an infinite series as a Riemann integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, summation, riemann-sum

Edit: I've modified the sums and integrals below into convergent sums and integrals, but my questions are still the same - how can I convert sums into integrals legitimately?  As far as I know, the sole requirement is for mesh(p) to shrink to zero.  But I am unsure about any requirements (if any at all) for the discrete variable $n$ before converting it to a continuous variable $t$.  Thanks,

I've done all of the necessary background reading on Riemman sums and integrals, but perhaps posting my naive thoughts would help me understand it a little deeper:

So, would this limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^2} x $$

...convert to this Riemann integral

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2}dt?$$

I am thinking that the factor $x$ would play the role of mesh(p) for some partition, $p$.  Since $x \to 0$, this factor converts to the integration factor $dt$.

But does the discrete variable $n$ ... convert to the continuous variable $t$?  Or, do we also need $n$ to shrink to $0$, too?  So that what I really need is

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{n^2x} x $$

in order for it to be a legitimate Riemann sum that converts to the above Riemann integral.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Thanks so much @Bungo, I have modified the question now so that the sums and integrals are convergent :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t) = 1/t^2$ and suppose want to approximate $\int_1^{\infty}f(t) dt$ as a Riemann sum.

Suppose we use rectangles of equal width, say $x$. Then the edges of the rectangles occur at the points $t= 1, 1+x, 1+2x, 1+3x, \ldots$. We can express this concisely as a sequence $t_n = 1+nx$, where $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.

Let us consider two approximations.

**Approximation from below**

Here, we choose the height of each rectangle as tall as possible so that the rectangle remains entirely below the graph of the function. Since $f$ is decreasing, this means that we choose the height of the rectangle so that its upper **right** corner touches the function. So, the height of the first rectangle will be $f(t_1)$, the height of the second rectangle will be $f(t_2)$, etc.

Then the sum of the areas of these rectangles is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(t_n)x$$
since $f(t_n)$ is the height of the $n$th rectangle, and every rectangle has width $x$. Since $f(t_n) = f(1+nx) = 1/(1+nx)^2$, this becomes
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx)^2}$$
and we would expect that as we make the width $x$ of the rectangles small, this should converge to the integral of $f$:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx)^2} = \int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}dt$$

**Approximation from above**

In this case, we choose the height of each rectangle as short as possible so that the rectangle remains above the graph of the function. Since $f$ is decreasing, this means that we choose the height of the rectangle so that its upper **left** corner touches the function. So, the height of the first rectangle will be $f(t_0)$, the height of the second rectangle will be $f(t_1)$, etc.

Then the sum of the areas of these rectangles is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(t_n)x$$
Since $f(t_n) = f(1+nx) = 1/(1+nx)^2$, this becomes
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx)^2}$$
Notice that the only difference versus approximation from below is that the sum starts at $n=0$ instead of $n=1$.

As before, if we make the width $x$ small, we would expect that in the limit, we should get the integral:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx)^2} = \int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2} dt$$

---

Now let's check that the above makes sense in terms of convergence. Let us define $L(x)$ and $U(x)$ to be the lower and upper approximations (i.e., the approximations from below and above, respectively). Therefore,
$$L(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx)^2}$$
and
$$U(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+nx)^2}$$
It's easy to see that for each fixed $x \geq 0$, both sums converge absolutely, so $L(x)$ and $U(x)$ are well defined. Moreover, their difference is simply the $n=0$ term:
$$U(x) - L(x) = \frac{x}{(1+0x)^2} = x$$
Therefore, as $x \to 0$, we have
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\ (U(x) - L(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0}\ x = 0$$
which shows that the difference between the upper and lower approximations converges to zero as we shrink the rectangle widths to zero. Since the integral $\int_1^{\infty}(1/t^2)dt$ is sandwiched between these two approximations, both $U(x)$ and $L(x)$ converge to $\int_1^{\infty}(1/t^2)dt = 1$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Hi @Bungo, thank you so much for this amazingly clear and pretty write-up.  I love your explanation on how the error term converges to zero.  And thanks, especially, for putting your write-up in the context of a problem that we were just discussing last night.  It couldn't be more perfect practice :-)  Have a great night, Bungo!  Hope to hear from you soon,

Answer (score 1):

The first expression is the product of a convergent sum to zero, and only this. Those. value of the first expression can not be determined.
The second expression is a divergent integral, its value is $+\infty$.
The connection between them is missing.

Comment: Hi @YuriNegometyanov, I have modified my question so that the example sums and integrals are convergent.  What do you think now?  In converting to a Riemann integral, does the discrete variable $n$ from the summation first have to "shrink" to zero, just like how mesh(p) is required to shrink to zero?  Also, the integral I have $\int \frac{1}{t^2}$ -- what would be its associated Riemann sum? Would it be $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{1}{n}$?  Thanks,

Comment: Now they are 0 and 1, but the connection is missing again. It can appear when $x$  becomes the parameter of series, but it is a zero factor.